# How would you interpret this question on values?

Tags: meaning

I think I will rephrase this question.

How would you interpret "**impact on values"**?

For example, would a possible impact on values be that that value is no longer important to the person? Say, a person values trust, and placed his trust in another person. However, the second person broke the first person's trust. What would be the impact **on** the first person's value?

Comment: Show context ...

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Can you provide some context, please, so the answer can be more accurate? You can edit your own posts regardless of your current reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that we are talking about the values of "society", to make sense the second sentence would need to be about someone's decision making people start telling lies, short-changing old ladies, cheating on their spouses and declaring a hatred for motherhood and apple pie. I don't think anyone has the power to do this.

Of course, it might be corprat-speak. Corprats love talking about the Values of the company, as long as they don't have to practice them. The CEO's decision to do blah-blah has an impact on Acme's Values of Efficiency, Quality, Customer Service and Excessive Capitals. Yawn. Yes, I could see that.

Comment: And, as you're saying, it's "having an impact"; "causing" is much lower in frequency.